# PosgreSQL падает при определенном запросе. Какие лимиты нужно поднять?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Postgres 9.5
Ubuntu 16.04

Постгрес падает с ошибкой:

> server process (PID 14328) has terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault

и дальше указан запрос который привел к падению. В большинстве случаев это один и тот же запрос, но есть еще несколько, приводящих к падению, но реже.
Запрос с DISTINCT ON по таблице со 150 000 записей. Не запредельная нагрузка должна быть.

Насколько я понимаю, упирается в ограничение по памяти. Только какой? В конфиге постгреса поднять какой-то лимит, или в системе?

Comment: может лучше посмотреть как этот запрос оптимизировать можно?

Comment: Да уже прикидывал как оптимизировать. Но считаю, что и при таком запросе падать не должно. Хочется поднять лимит, потом запросы оптимизировать.

Comment: вот ссылка на базовую конфу постгреса в зависимости от железа http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/, путь до конфига смотрим запросом show config_file. Тонкая настройка индивидуальна для каждого проекта.

Comment: Спасибо. Воспользовался. Подкорректировал под себя конечно, стало заметно лучше.